# The linearness of extension of linear bounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let we have the following bounded linear operator $$T: D(T)\rightarrow Y$$ such that $D(T)$ is the domain and it is a vector space and $Y$ is a Banach space . 
Then it has an extension $$G: W\rightarrow Y$$ such that $W=CL(D(T))$ .
Maybe my following question is so stupid but I need some help please 
How can I prove that the operator $G$ is linear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define $G$ as follows: if $x_n \in D(T)$ and $w \in W$ with $x_n \to w$, then $G(y) = \lim_{n \to \infty} T(x_n)$ (use boundedness of $T$ to show that this is well-defined).  Then if $x_n \to w$ and $y_n \to v$, and $a,b$ are scalars, you want to show that 
$G(aw + bv) = a G(w) + b G(v)$.  Well, what sequence (defined in terms of  $x_n$, $y_n$, $a$, and $b$) converges to $a w + b v$?